# Connecting 5 monitors to graphic card - AMD Radeon HD cards configuration

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

First of all I am new to this hardware stuff. I have few graphics cards with me:

1. 1x1 AMD Radeon HD 6670
2. 1x2 AMD Radeon HD 6600
3. 1x1 AMD Radeon HD 6450
4. 1x1 AMD Radeon HD 3600

I have my PC setup in this way:

With 1st option 2 Monitors and with other three options the graphic card connected to only one monitor each.

Now I want to connect my 5 Monitors to one PC.

My Questions are:

1. Is there any way that using any one of the Graphics card I can connect my 5 monitors?
2. If first question answer is "NO" then is it possible that I can use a combination of graphic cards to connect my 5 monitors to one PC.
3. If second Answer is "YES" then which combination will give better results in performance and quality.

I have 3 PCIe Slots, So I guess i can install multiple graaphics card, but I am not sure as I have not tried it before.

Also, I have gone through AMD website and it says that I can connect upto 6 monitors and there is a utility also on the website, but I am unable to figure out the way, here is the link:

Set Up AMD eyefinity technology configuration tool

Although I am googling it and even youtube but there are certain ways found but everything seems to be very fast and I am unable to grasp. Like connectors and convertors and other stuffs, however I didn't found any relevent result for multi GPUs.

Looking forward for you all support.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can do it with either of the AMD 6000 cards, if they have a displayport connector.  Each card would have to support two monitors via a combination of HDMI, VGA, and DVI, and 3 monitors via DisplayPort.  If the monitors don't have a displayport connector, you'll need an adapter, too.  See the bottom of this page:
 http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/amd-eyefinity.en.html

Here is what is hopefully a simpler explanation:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DrivingMultipleDisplaysFromaSingleDisplayPort.aspx

It has a very clear picture of a displayport "hub" that would support 3 monitors.

Here is a picture of a Sapphire Radeon 6670 card that shows the displayport connectors fairly clearly.